# why pattern syntax is different on fc-list with other fontconfig command like fc-match

Tags: fontconfig

I just find the syntax of pattern in fc-list is different with other fontconfig command like fc-match and fc-pattern
For fc-list, I have to add ":" in order to list all sans font

```
hongy19@WSL ~$ fc-list sans
hongy19@WSL ~$ fc-list :sans|head -2
/home/hongy19/.local/share/fonts/opentype/public/almfixed/almfixed.otf: ALM Fixed:style=Regular
/home/hongy19/.local/share/fonts/opentype/public/garamond-math/Garamond-Math.otf: Garamond\-Math:style=Regular
```

but in fc-match and fc-pattern, ":" is not needed

```
hongy19@WSL ~$ fc-pattern :sans
Pattern has 0 elts (size 0)
        (null):

hongy19@WSL ~$ fc-pattern sans
Pattern has 1 elts (size 16)
        family: "sans"(s)
```

Comment: "Why has the developer made a decision like this?" - might be best to ask from the developer, if the answer's not in the documentation.

Comment: see answer on https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/issues/358